# JQUERY knob value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am using jQuery knob and want to offer users to enter values for the knobs like '**time**' from 7.00 (am) till 5.00 (pm) in 30min steps.
So the translation should be something like this, but don't know how to achieve?

User enter >> Value changes to X

- 7.00 >> 0
- 7.30 >> 5
- 8.00 >> 10
- ...
- 12.00 >> 50
- 12.30 >> 55
- 1.00 >> 60
- 1.30 >> 65
- ...
- 5.00 >> 100

Any help would be appreciated!

How to embed the function to existing HTML / PHP page?
I have a jquery knob in my html like this:

```
<html>
<input class="knob" data-width="90" data-height="90" data-step="5" value="0">
</html>
```

Thank you!
Roman

Comment: Hey @Roman, I have an answer, but you need to update your question with some sample code so it can be reopened.  Otherwise I can't answer it.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I added a code snippet.

Comment: It looks like this won't get the votes to reopen.  Here's a snippet of code from my answer:
*function formatTime(v) {
  const hour = Math.floor(v - 1) % 12 + 1;
  const minute = (v * 100 % 100) * .6;
  return \`${hour.toFixed(0)}:${minute.toFixed(0).padStart(2, '0')}\`;
}
$(".knob").knob({
  min: 7,
  max: 17,
  step: .5,
  format: formatTime
});*

Answer (score 1):

simple math problem you know every 5 is 30 minutes so multiply it

```js
function getTS(x) {
  var totalMins = Math.floor(x/5) * 30 + 420;
  var hours = Math.floor(totalMins / 60);
  var hoursFormatted = ((hours + 11) % 12 + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  var minsFormatted = (totalMins % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  var amPM = hours < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
  return hoursFormatted + ":" + minsFormatted +  amPM;
}
console.log(getTS(0))
console.log(getTS(5))
console.log(getTS(100))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and great answer. Poorly I don't know how to implement this in my existing HTML page. So I see my limits. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Well I have never used that plugin and have no clue what you are actually trying to do. I assume it has an onchange event that gives you the value.